# No read access to repo Jitpack error

Tags: android, jitpack

My Github account is private. I'm trying to create a dependency in Jitpack of my github repo project. But its throwing "No read access to repo" error. Can anyone help me to fix this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y12ds.png

Comment: Put here your `lib/build.gradle` and your `project/build.gradle`

Comment: Don't forget of create a `release` on your repo

Answer (score 6):

According to the [JitPack website](https://jitpack.io/private), in order to use private repositories via JitPack, you need to authorize JitPack on GitHub and add your token into `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` in the following format:

```
authToken=AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN
```

Then use `authToken` as the `username` in your `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            credentials { username authToken }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thannks for your response, Can't able to access my repo for building the dependency. Once it build successfully then we need auth token to access that dependency.

Comment: So, we don't need to pay Jitpack for private repositories?

Comment: I don't know. I gave this answer 5 years ago and I don't use JitPack on daily basis. You need to ask JitPack support  or test it yourself to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for granting read access to your Github/Bitbucket/Gitlab private repositories : https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/#set-up

For reference:

To start using private repositories you will first need to grant JitPack access. Open https://jitpack.io/private and follow the steps:

1. Click Authorize to get your personal authentication token. Each
   member of your team should to get their own token.
2. Add the token to $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties:

> authToken=AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN

3. Then use authToken as the username in your build.gradle:

> repositories {
> maven {
> url "https://jitpack.io"
> credentials { username authToken }
> }
> }